# datatables - undefined method 'orm' after update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatables

when starting the test web server, the error below comes up. Unfortunately my colleague, who is on vacation now, did some updates on my server, and i dont know what exactly he has done. The application was running before... I googled the error, but didnt find anything useful. Iam still using the same gem version, so iam pretty clueless what to do next.

error:

```
/myProject/config/initializers/ajax_datatables_rails.rb:6:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined method `orm=' for #<AjaxDatatablesRails::Configuration:0x0000000004072c00> (NoMethodError)
```

config/initializers/ajax_datatables_rails.rb

```
 AjaxDatatablesRails.configure do |config|
  # available options for db_adapter are: :pg, :mysql, :mysql2, :sqlite, :sqlite3
  config.db_adapter = :pg

  # available options for orm are: :active_record, :mongoid
  config.orm = :active_record
end
```

Gemfile.lock

```
ajax-datatables-rails (0.3.1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an old version of this gem. This config is available on version `0.4.x`.

You might want to take a look here: https://github.com/jbox-web/ajax-datatables-rails/tree/v0.4.x#configuration

Comment: you are right. i set the gem to v0.4.0, and suddenly everything worked. Iam wondering, why it suddenly stopped workng, since i didnt need that in the past..